# Для чего еще используется ключевое слово this?

Tags: javascript

Знаю что ключевое слово this, если функция является конструктором используется для того чтобы можно было обратиться к новосозданному объекту, например к свойствам объекта. 
Например:

```
function User(argname,argage){
    this.name = argname;         //  c помощью this обращаемся к свойству name объекта vasya        
    this.age = argage;        
}   

var vasya = new User("Вася",20);

//новосозданный обьект
var vasya ={
name = "Вася",             
age = 20;
}
```

Тут все просто и понятно. Но как говорит документация this также может иметь другое значение в зависимости от контекста. Я гуглил но когда начал читать другие варианты использования (его значение), чем больше я читал тем больше я запутивался, возможно мне нужно что б кто-то просто человеческим языком объяснил без воды.

Пример из жизни:

Бейсбольная бита используется для: 
1) игры в бейсбол
2) как элемент самозащиты
3) как выбивалка для ковров (допустим такой вариант=))
...
и т.д.

Хочу что б так же вы мне объяснили по ключевому слову this, какое еще его использование в зависимости от контекста:

Ключевое слово this используется(его значение):
1) для того чтобы можно было обратиться к новосозданному объекту в функции-конструкторе.
... // я привел пример выше

2) ..... // вариант использования
..... // пример маленького и просто кода

3) ..... // вариант использования
..... // пример маленького и просто кода

и т.д. сколько можете вариантов привести....

Comment: понимая суть, можно самому принять решение для чего использовать тот или иной инструмент, this это контекст вызова функции.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов это такой саммон господина Grundy ?))

Comment: да, хотел добавить что частенько this можно использовать для выстрела себе в ногу в начале забега.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ахаха ) Нет.С начала проголосовал потом передумал ничего серьезного не обращай внимание ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начнем:

**this** используется для того чтобы получить доступ к текущему объекту.

Пример:

```
console.log(this);
```

Что мы получаем ?
Ответ:Объект `window` со всеми его свойствами.

То есть он указывает на **глобальный объект window.**

Второй пример:

```
const team = {
    name:'Groot',
 }
```

У нас есть объект `team` и нам нужно внутри этого объекта получить доступ к имени персонажа.
Как мы делаем это

```
const team = {
    name:'Groot',
    showTeam(){
        console.log(this.name);
    }
}
team.showTeam(); // //Groot
```

У тебя может возникнуть вопрос этот пример мы можем так же написать без **this** какая между ними разница :

```
const team = {
    name:'Groot',
    showTeam(){
        console.log(team.name);
    }
 }
team.showTeam(); // //Groot
```

Разница следующая если ты на основе первого объекта `team`  создашь новый объект `z` он будет ссылаться на основной (`team`) объект.Вот так:

```
const team = {
    name:'Groot',
    showTeam(){
        console.log(team.name);
    }
 }
const z = Object.create(team);
z.name = "z";
z.showTeam(); // Groot
```

Получили Groot - а:
А если бы был **this** вместо `team` вот так `console.log(this.name);` Получили бы проста строку z так как и должно было быть.

Пример третий добавляем стражу в список:

У нас есть такой код.

```
const team = {
    prefix:"Guardian Of galaxy",
    list:["Guill","Gamora","Drax","Groot"],
}
```

И мы хотим внутри объекта получить доступ ко всему списку используем всем известный `forEach`

```
    const team = {
       prefix:"Guardian Of galaxy",
       list:["Guill","Gamora","Drax","Groot"],
       showTeam(){
           this.list.forEach(function(heroe){
              console.log(heroe);
           })
       }
    }

    team.showTeam(); // Guill, Gamor ,Drax ,Groot
```

И получаем всех героев.Но что если мы захотим туда добавить наш префикс чтобы было вот так: `Guardian Of galaxy Guill`

Для этого делаем так

```
const team = {
    prefix:"Guardian Of galaxy",
    list:["Guill","Gamora","Drax","Groot"],
    showTeam(){
        this.list.forEach(function(heroe){
            console.log(this.prefix + " " + heroe);
        })
    }
}

team.showTeam(); // undefined Guill, undefined Gamor ,undefined Drax ,undefined Groot
```

Мы получили `undefined Guill` почему?Потому что это функция не метод объекта и он ссылается на глобальный объект **window**.

Но как это исправить?

К счастью у **forEach** есть второй необязательный параметр this.Связываем `this` с текущим объектом и все.

```
const team = {
    prefix:"Guardian Of galaxy",
    list:["Guill","Gamora","Drax","Groot"],
    showTeam(){
        this.list.forEach(function(heroe){
            console.log(this.prefix + " " + heroe);
        },this )
    }
}

team.showTeam(); // Guardian Of galaxy Guill, Guardian Of galaxy Gamora , Guardian Of galaxy Drax  , Guardian Of galaxy Groot
```